# Как захватить вывод сторонней программы в командной строке?

Tags: cmd, java

В процессе работы моего приложения на java запускаю стороннюю программу через командную строку: как получить то, что это приложение возвращает в консоль?
Запускаю так:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\findbugs.bat");
```

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\findbugs.bat").getInputStream();

Comment: да, это так

Answer (score 1):

из комментариев

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\findbugs.bat").getInputStream();
```

> woesss 6 фев '14 в 8:11